# nginx with upstream occasitionaly delays exact 1 minute

Tags: nginx, delay, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, upstream

> Inner-System

**HARDWARE** : Xeon E-2236 x 32GB x 1TB SSD ) with 4 servers.
only for **load balancing**, for **performancing** x 2ea , for **db CRUD**

**SOFTWARE** : centos 7, nginx 1.18, node v12.22.1

When external connection to server, **load-balancing server** send to **reverse-proxy( performancing server )** and calculate it. when calculate is completed, send it to **db-server** to record it.
it

This work needs low performance, so always **CPU usage is 0~2%, RAM usage is 3~7%, IO WAIT is 0%**

> **PROBLEM IS**

When external request is arrived to load-sever,
request is randomly **delays** **perfectly 1 minute** and it sended to reverse-proxy server.
and While request's 1 min delay, restarting of load-server's nginx ( systemctl restart nginx ) complete request immediately with no errors. it handled well.

**Mysteriously, this problem delays perfectly 1 minute** ( 1min 0.02s ~ 1min 0.1s spends).
when 1 minute later, it seems to normal ( responses in 50ms serveral times ) but when request from same device, it delays 1 min per 5 min

but perfectly copy of external http connection x **5000 requests** send it from load-server to load-server with curl,

load-server send to perform-server and perform-server to db-server spends lower then **average 50ms**
Checked all nginx to reverse-proxy port and responses, it is lower then **average 50ms**, too.

same in **nuxt-server** and **api-server**.
they are running from perform-server - each localhost:3000, localhost:3001 ~ 3012

load-nginx.conf :

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  auto;
            
error_log  logs/error.log;
events {
use epoll;
worker_connections  4096;
multi_accept   off;
}


http {
client_max_body_size 300M;
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  35;
reset_timedout_connection on;
send_timeout 15;


upstream nuxtserver-ssl {
    ip_hash;
    server 10.10.10.21:500;
    server 10.10.10.22:500;
}
upstream apiserver-ssl {
   server 10.10.10.21:465;
   server 10.10.10.22:465;
   server 10.10.10.21:466;
   server 10.10.10.22:466;
   server 10.10.10.21:467;
   server 10.10.10.22:467;
}

# HTTPS server
#
server {
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/ipdeny.conf;

    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  subdomain.example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/ssl/__example_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/ssl/__example_com.key;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    access_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/ssl-access.log combined;
    error_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/ssl-error.log;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://nuxtserver-ssl;
    }
    location /api/ {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_pass http://apiserver-ssl;
            proxy_connect_timeout 3;
            proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know that this was OP's issue, but I ran into similar issues in my docker swarm which were all relating to IPV6 support.

My approach was to ensure that I was always proxying to an IPV4 address, rather than leaving it up to chance.

Relating to localhost:

```yaml
server {
    ...
    location / {
        # This would occasionally take 1 minute:
        # proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000;

        # This is always quick:
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

And relating to docker-internal DNS queries:

```yaml
server {
    ...

    # This would occasionally take 1 minute:
    # resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;

    # This is always quick:
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ipv6=off;

    location / {
        set $target myproject-web;
        proxy_pass  http://$target:8000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue, nginx + Docker Swarm. I was able to get a fix by only changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, no need to ipv6=off just yet it seems. Thanks @Aaron

Comment: in `proxy_pass` by replacing `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;` to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;` it resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you man!! localhost > 127.0.0.1 solve my problem.